# Content load in a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, bootstrap-modal

I'm generating a series of records using ColdFusion 2016 that looks like this:

```
        <tr >
          <td scope="row">#POLL_NAME#</th>
          <td>
            <a href="/customcf/extras/polls/manager.cfm?svc=gp&pollID=#POLL_ID#" id="pollQ_#variables.count#">Retrieve Poll</a>

          </td>
          <td>#POLL_START#</td>
          <td>#POLL_END#</td>
          <td><cfif IS_ACTIVE is 1><i class="fa fa-toggle-on" id="activeToggleOn_#variables.count#" data-pollID = "#POLL_ID#"></i><cfelse><i class="fa fa-toggle-off" id="activeToggleOff_#variables.count#" data-pollID = "#POLL_ID#" style="color:red"></i></cfif> </td>
        </tr>

        <cfset variables.count ++>
    </cfloop>
```

The link is supposed to open a bootstrap modal window with the data for each poll, the link passes and ID to grab th data:

```
<script>
    var cnt = #variables.pollData.recordcount#;

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        for(k = 0; k < cnt; k++) { 
            jQuery("##pollQ_" + k).on("click", function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var localURL = "";
                var localURL = jQuery(this).attr('href');

                jQuery('##pollView').modal('show');

                jQuery('##pollView').on("shown.bs.modal", function(){
                    jQuery(this).find(".modal-body").load(localURL);
                });

                jQuery('##pollView').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                    jQuery(this).removeData('bs.modal');
                    jQuery('##pollView .modal-content').empty();
                });

                return false;
            })
      }
     })
</script>
```

The modal opens but the data doesn't show up. When I open the Chrome developer tools I see multiple calls to the injected url per click

```
 /customcf/extras/polls/manager.cfm?svc=gp&pollID=31
 /customcf/extras/polls/manager.cfm?svc=gp&pollID=31
 /customcf/extras/polls/manager.cfm?svc=gp&pollID=32
```

It appears as though the localURL var isn't clearing except that 32 is the current one clicked. As i moved down the list of polls the calls compound on each other.

I'm at a loss, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try placing `jQuery('##pollView').modal('show');` after the shown and hidden functions

Comment: Why are you referencing as `##pollView` or even `##pollQ_` --- why not simply `#pollView` or `#pollQ_`?

Comment: @Rushikumar - In CF, `#` is a reserved character. If enclosed in `cfoutput` it must be escaped by using `##`, but it has no impact on the generated JS. The JS code will only have a single pound sign, ie `#pollView`.

Comment: I'm closer...  I've added a class .pollQA to each record and looped over them with jQuery.each()

I'm closer...  I've added a class .pollQA to each record's a tag and looped over them using the jQuery each() function. This gives a somewhat different output, the id changes correctly but I'm still seeing multiple iterations

here's the jsfiddle  [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/4303s2yf/)

Comment: I'm never a fan of having multiple listeners, as it often results in strangeness like events firing multiple times because coding is hard. If you simply add a single listener, say on a common class, then you wouldn't need to loop and have a separate listener for each anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity try:

```
<a href="/customcf/extras/polls/manager.cfm?svc=gp&pollID=#POLL_ID#" class="loadMeToModal">Retrieve Poll</a>
```

Remove your loop and just do

```
jQuery(".loadMeToModal").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var localURL = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('##pollView').find(".modal-body").load(localURL); //Load the modal
    jQuery('##pollView').modal('show'); //Show the modal
});
```

I do exactly what you are doing across my sites and have a single class that always triggers it essentially like this so I can have a single listener to handle everything instead of a unique listener for each link.

Your code was adding bootstrap listeners each time the anchor was clicked. You don't need to do that. You only need to add those listeners once, but in reality, with what you are doing, you don't need those listeners at all. Simply class the load on click and then the show.

When they close the modal, there is no need to clear the data in there. If you want to you can but just add the following code OUTSIDE the click even function so it looks like this.

```
jQuery(".loadMeToModal").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var localURL = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('##pollView').find(".modal-body").load(localURL); //Load the modal
    jQuery('##pollView').modal('show'); //Show the modal
});
jQuery('##pollView').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () { //When the modal closes
    jQuery('##pollView .modal-content').empty(); //Clear the modal
});
```

Or if you want the modal to show and then load, you could clear the data on click and have everything in a single listener.

```
jQuery(".loadMeToModal").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var localURL = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('##pollView').find(".modal-body").empty(); //Clear the modal
    jQuery('##pollView').modal('show'); //Show the modal
    jQuery('##pollView').find(".modal-body").load(localURL); //Load the modal
});
```

To explain what your code is doing, each time someone clicks one of your links, your code is adding a listener saying "If the modal is shown, load this data". So the first time you click one, it does that. The second time someone clicks the same link, you're adding the listener again, so it fires twice. So on and so fourth.

If you really want to simply fix what you have and can't use classes, do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    for(k = 0; k < cnt; k++) { 
        jQuery("##pollQ_" + k).on("click", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var localURL = "";
            var localURL = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            jQuery(this).find(".modal-body").load(localURL);
            jQuery('##pollView').modal('show');
        });
    }
    jQuery('##pollView').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        jQuery(this).removeData('bs.modal');
        jQuery('##pollView .modal-content').empty();
    });
});
```

Comment: I do something similar, but more generic: `<a href="{url}" class="{{class_selector}}" data-target="{{id_of _target_div}}">`. Then define `var target` as the value of the data attribute, reference `jQuery("#" + target)` and finally chain `.find().empty().load()` to clear any previous content the next time you load the modal.